# How can I add interaction term or transform the variable in randomforest?

Tags: r, predictive-models, random-forest

I am making predictive model with randomforest in R's randomForest package. I wonder how determine independent variable's transformation and adding interaction term. In regression model, the reason why I do these things is to assure linearity. What should I judge transformation and adding interaction term?